# How can I get an application context inside a method of a Spring RestController annotated class

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a simple app using the @SpringBootAnnotation with a single call on the *main* method:

`SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);`

On App.java I am also defining a couple of @BeanS, which give the instance of drivers to access external services:

```
@Bean
public APEWebservice ape() {
  return new APEWebservice(apeWebAddress + ":" + apePort);
}
```

Then, on the method of one of my @RestControllerS I want to make an access to these beans, so that I can make further calls to these other services, something along these lines:

```
@PostMapping(path="/talk", consumes = "application/json")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
public Talk talk(@RequestBody InputTalk body) throws ConfigurationException {
  ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(App.class);
  APEWebservice ape = context.getBean("ape", APEWebservice.class);
  String DRSString = ape.getSoloOutput(input, OutputType.DRSXML);
  ((ConfigurableApplicationContext)context).close();
  try {
    Commanded transformed = Preprocessor.transform(body.getContent(), DRSString);
    return new Talk(counter.incrementAndGet(), transformed.execute());
  }
  catch (WrongCommandException e) {
      return new Talk(counter.incrementAndGet(), e.getError());
  }
}
```

This looks very ugly, and I am certain I am completely missing the point of Spring and dependency injection. Is there a way to access the context without having to initialize it for every call to the API?

I am using SpringBoot 2.2.1

Answer (score 1):

What about injecting?

```
@Autowired
private final APEWebservice service;

//code
@PostMapping(path="/talk", consumes = "application/json")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
public Talk talk(@RequestBody InputTalk body) throws ConfigurationException {
String DRSString = service.getSoloOutput(input, OutputType.DRSXML);
```

Comment: You cannot autowire static fields

Comment: Doesn't it still need to be initialized? The compiler doesn't seem to like that...

Comment: Well, I'm obviously missing something here then, because just adding that annotation does not do the trick for me. The compiler does not allow me to proceed, saying the variable needs to be initialised.